# Deploy app directly to windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I made an app that reduces fractions. The app is just for me. I'd like to put it on my phone but it appears the only way to do that is by creating a developer account ($19) and uploading it to the windows store.

Is there a way to deploy my app directly to my phone without going through the windows store or creating a developers account?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you can Dev-Unlock your phone using the free App Studio: http://appstudio.windows.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you only need a Microsoft account (aka Live Id), which is free:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

"If you don’t have a developer account, you can only register one device to use for app development"

I don't know how you made the app, but if you have a Visual Studio solution then the connected (and registered) phone should show up in VS and once you started the app from there it is installed on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is developer unlocked, you can also use deploy app to your phone using application deployment tool.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632395.aspx